# Redirecionamento de subdomínio em .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, subdomínio

Estou tentando fazer um redirecionamento de subdomínio no .htaccess da seguinte forma:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^testephp\.com\.br
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]+)\.testephp\.com\.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://testephp.com.br/index2.php [L,QSA]
```

se eu entro com a url http://testephp.com.br funciona certinho, tudo ok, porém, ao digitar algo semelhante a http://xpto.testephp.com.br não sou redirecionado para lugar nenhum, apenas recebo o erro: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

Estou usando o xampp em minha máquina local.

Answer (score 1):

Essa configuração você deve fazer na configuração de virtual host do seu domínio:

```
ServerName       testephp.com.br
ServerAlias xpto.testephp.com.br
```

Além disso, não se esqueça de editar seu arquivo `hosts` para entender as requisições a ambos os domínios como requisições para `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Meu vhost está assim:
`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@testephp.com.br
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/testephp"
    ServerName testephp.com.br
    ServerAlias *.testephp.com.br
    <directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/testephp">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: Até onde eu sei, não é possível usar um wildcard no `ServerAlias`. Você deve discriminar os subdomínios um a um.

Comment: Entendi, mas como faço então para ter subdomínios dinâmicos?

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada e parece que é possível sim. Dá uma olhada nesse tutorial: http://blog.calcatraz.com/wildcard-subdomains-in-apache-1422

Comment: Amigo obrigado mas não consegui. Continuarei minhas pesquisas e caso consiga alguma coisa posto aqui para ajudar outros que tiverem o mesmo problema.